# Show tar files sizes

Tags: linux, tar

I've got a bad backup script including an unwanted file. The .tar.gz backup file is 5gig big and I'd like to get a list of every file in the archive and their size.

Is that possible ? How would you do it ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This should list all files and detailed information about them:

```
tar -ztvf somefile.tar.gz
```

Comment: `-t` (list) and `-v` (verbose, like `ls -l` use a long listing format)

Comment: -z isn't strictly needed, for a `.tgz` file just using `-tvf` was enough.

Answer (score 7):

Use

```
tar --list --verbose --gunzip --file backup.tar.gz > backup_list.txt
```

to create a file containing a list of all the files in your archive.

You can then `grep foo backup_list.txt` to find things, or edit, sed, cut, view, etc.